# Is there a (performance) benefit in having dedicated DatagramSockets for sending and receiving UDP datagrams?

Tags: java, performance, sockets, udp

I have some datagram sockets, one is for input and other for output with different ports. Is there any reason for doing it? Is for best performance?

```
| <- Receiver, accept and accumulate some packets received from client
| <-> Proccess, request packets from Receiver, process and put some response into Sender
| -> Sender, just immediate send
```

I am thinking about combine Receiver and Sender and use one socket.
Receiver and Sender are some modules. They may be initialized in other part of the programm (for example in communication between other modules over the web).

Comment: What do you mean by "having some sockets"? Are these TCP/IP sockets, web sockets, something else? How does the application use these sockets?

Comment: datagram sockets are

Comment: Can you post some code that shows what you have? There may be reasons like wanting a different source port number for sent packets than the port on which you receive packets.

Comment: So they are TCP/UDP sockets.

Comment: udp sockets are. The main question is about performance for using 2 sockets separately. One is for receive and other for send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no performance benefit, in the sense that data does not travel any faster or in greater quantities with two sockets than with one.

There are other good reasons for using different udp sockets to receive and send, related to how the application protocol design and to reliability.

Each socket has send and receive buffers of its own. If either of these buffers becomes full, packets will be dropped. In other words, using a single socket for multiple purposes may increase the risk of packet drops.

Also, with different sockets you can use different local ports. A benefit from different local ports is it gives you an easy way to handle separate streams of packets for different clients. You can see an example of this in the design of the TFTP protocol https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol